# Norton 360 Won't Run After Using Norton Power Eraser?

Tags: anti-virus, norton-360

I have a Toshiba laptop running Windows 7, ran Norton Power Eraser, instructions said Norton 360 would be up again after a computer restart, but Norton 360 didn't come back up. How do I get Norton 360 to run again without repurchasing it?

Comment: Contact the Norton help desk, I'd guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you have purchased a valid license from Norton, you should have a serial number that you have got after you had paid. 
Install the latest version of Norton 360 and activate it with your serial number. Keep in mind that it's the very same license you have originally purchased, so you will have the respective number of days remaining until the license expires. (i.e. if you have bought a 1-year license 65 days ago, you will have 300 days left, no matter if you used the product in that time or not.)

Also remember  that the license it typically for 3 PCs (depending on what you have purchased exactly), but its **does not** mean you can only install it 3 times, you can't just have 3x Norton 360s activated at the *same time*.

Comment: You can get the installer from here: http://ca.norton.com/downloads-trial-norton-360 As said by @matan129 , just use your old license key.